# What should I do with a thread when it's done ? leave it or abort it?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, abort

I create normal threads in `asp.net` application. After the thread is done what should I do ? leave it (it will get back to thread pool) or abort it.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(work));
```

Comment: Creating a thread in that manner does *not* use the threadpool.

Comment: So what happens with this threads if I leave them exit the context ?

Comment: As Ani points out the code above does not give you a thread pool thread. Take a look at BackgroudWorker or even the Task class if you're on .NET 4.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Once the thread has finished running the code in `work` it will exit. However, starting new threads may be quite expensive, so unless `work` does a lot of work, you're much better off using a thread pool thread as it amortizes the cost of creating threads by reusing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave it. There is no sense in creating a pointless exception.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the `IDisposable` interface exists *specifically* for the scenario where some shared resource needs to be released. (It has been applied in other contexts as well, of course; but that is the situation it was originally meant for.)

Now consider that the managed `Thread` class **does *not* implement `IDisposable`** and you might guess (correctly) that it does not require any specific cleanup beyond normal handling by the GC.

Answer (score 1):

using threadpools in C#

```
   [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      foreach(var  fileNamePath in DirectoryFiles)
      {
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadPoolCallback, fileNamePath);
      }
    }

  public void ThreadPoolCallback(object threadContext)
  {
       //do something 
  }
```

The threadPool in .NET handles everything else.